# Running a py file from cmd that contain matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cmd

I am trying to run a python file (`test.py`) from command line in windows that contain a matplotlib plot. The file is running but the plot is only appearing for a fraction of second.

Here is the content of `test.py`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
```

I am using the following command in cmd:

```
ipython test.py --matplotlib
```

The output is

```
Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
```

The problem is the plot only appears for a fraction of second.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modify like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

And run like this:

```
python test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I like it

- You can create a .py file and copy your codes into it (or saving your codes in spyder or jupyter as .py file) and finally click on it.
- The cmd will be run automatically and your plot will be demonstrated. However, if you have imported some data from your directory (for example `C:\Users\PC_NAME`) you have to copy .py file to your directory and only click on it there.
- The reason clicking on .py file seems more satisfactory for me is because it gives a nice 3D view coming with cursor manipulation for rotation which jupyter does not support for matplotlib (unless you use other means of plotting like: **plotly** in jupyter)